# Checking if array value exists in a PHP

Tags: php, arrays, display

i am storing birtday dates in an array

```
$birthdays = array
 (
  array("Alex",5,12),
  array("Tom",2,20),
  array("Sarah",6,12),
  array("Anna",6,8) 
  array("Jonh",10,7)  );
```

i need html form(2 input textbox)i have to enter the date,press the button and if the date is exist,will print the name of person who have a birthday today

Comment: You mean if a specific array is on your `$birthdays` array? and if yes display it?

Comment: How will be the input? 2 variables? like `$day = 20; $month = 2`?

Comment: yes,searching by date and display the name

Comment: i need html form(2 input textbox)i have to enter the date,press the button and if the date is exist,will print the name of person who have a birthday today

Comment: @AlexBazikalo You should ask another question as the question you just posed in the comments is not related to this question.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this...

```
$SearchValue = "Sarah"
foreach ($birthdays as $value)
{
    if (is_array($value))
    {
        if (in_array($SearchValue, $value)
        {
            //prints the inner array if the inner array contains your search value
            print_r($value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvote brigade has targeted my answer. It does exactly what OP has requested.

Comment: I wouldn't use `in_array` when the index is perfectly well defined. Use `if ($value[0] == $SearchValue)` instead.

Comment: When I wrote the answer @deceze , OP hadn't specified they wanted to search by any field, so I wrote it using `in_arary` so that it would search all fields in the array.

Comment: i need html form(2 input textbox)i have to enter the date,press the button and if the date is exist,will print the name of person who have a birthday today

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php

$birthdays = array
 (
  array("Alex",5,12),
  array("Tom",2,20),
  array("Sarah",6,12),
  array("Anna",6,8),
  array("Jonh",10,7)  
 );

 function getBirthdayNameByDate($birthdaysArray, $day, $month)
 {
     foreach($birthdaysArray as $array)
     {
         if($array[1] == $month && $array[2] == $day)
            return $array[0];
     }

     return null;

 }

$result = getBirthdayNameByDate($birthdays, 8, 6);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: what do var_dump($result);?

Comment: Shows the value stored in variable passed as argument. Its useful for debugging.

Comment: i need html form(2 input textbox)i have to enter the date,press the button and if the date is exist,will print the name of person who have a birthday today

Answer (score 0):

With this function:

```
function retrieveBirthdays( $birthdays, $month, $day=0 )
{
    return array_values
    (
        array_filter
        (
            $birthdays, 
            function( $row ) use( $month, $day ) 
            {
                if( $day ) return ( $row[1]==$month && $row[2]==$day );
                else       return ( $row[1]==$month );
            } 
        ) 
    );
}

print_r( retrieveBirthdays( $birthdays, 2, 20 ) );
```

will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Tom
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 20
        )

)
```

Instead, to obtain all june birthdays, you can use:

```
print_r( retrieveBirthdays( $birthdays, 6 ) );
```

and you will obtain:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sarah
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 12
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Anna
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 8
        )

)
```

---

- Read more about [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: i need html form(2 input textbox)i have to enter the date,press the button and if the date is exist,will print the name of person who have a birthday today

Comment: @AlexBazikalo to retrieve the name of person with today birthday: `$persons = retrieveBirthdays( $birthdays, 3, 9 ); $name = $persons[0][0]`. `$name` is your desired name. Side note: you think is totally impossible 2 persons with same birthday?

Answer (score -3):

```
$birthdays = array (
array("Alex",5,12),
array("Tom",2,20),
array("Sarah",6,12),
array("Anna",6,8), 
array("Jonh",10,7),
array()
);

foreach($birthdays as $birthday) {
if($birthday) {
echo $birthday[0]."<br/>";
echo $birthday[1]."<br/>";
echo $birthday[2]."<br/>";
}
}
```

See if above code helps, it simply has a if condtion in foreach to check that the array is not emptu

Comment: I see the question has been changed by the user. so based on the original question which was to just check if value exists, why this answer of mine is down voted?

Comment: i need html form(2 input textbox)i have to enter the date,press the button and if the date is exist,will print the name of person who have a birthday today